# How to get the Onesignal ID in the latest Flutter SDK version 5.0.0?

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I am trying to get the Onesignal ID which was previously available in v3.x.x but now only the subscription Id and the token are available from the `Onesignal.User.pushSubscription.id` property

Comment: Did anyone manage to get the OneSignal ID?